# Why was this question deleted by a mod?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569282/extract-php-coding-from-website/

It says "removed due to reasons of moderation" but nothing apparent was wrong with it.

I'm partial to it because it would have brought me to the 1k bracket.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was deleted by a moderator only after being *first* closed as "not a real question" by 5 regular members of the community. If you could see the page, it would say:

> ### closed as not a real question by [therefromhere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8331/therefromhere), [mcgrailm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234670/mcgrailm), [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b), [vascowhite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212940/vascowhite), [bažmegakapa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/468793/bazmegakapa) May 13 at 9:20
>
> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. See the FAQ for guidance on how to improve it.

I think that pretty well sums up what's wrong with the question. In full form, it looked like this:

> ### Extract php coding from website
>
> Basically i want to be able to extract php coding from this simple webhosting instead of just html
>
> http://uncopycat.zxq.net/
>
> I know it is possible but i'm still a newbie in php.
>
> [php](/questions/tagged/php)

I don't know about you, but I remain unconvinced that one was worth saving.

Comment: alright, thanks. I can't see the page since it was deleted

Comment: @Kevin Duke: This answer sums it up nicely. Sorry that I nope'd your 1k milestone right after you made it there though :( On the bright side, you got your first Nice Answer badge, and you get to make the milestone *again*, and everybody loves second chances!